# How to use Spotify Views API?

Tags: api, view, spotify

How do I use Spotifies Views API the right way?

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/views/index.html

I am trying to implement a throbber in a div, so I use this code:

```
    require(['$views/throbber#Throbber'], function(Throbber) {

      var favs = document.getElementById('favs');
      var throbber = Throbber.forElement(favs);

    });
```

But this is throwing an "ReferenceError: require is not defined". 
When I use it like this:

```
    var sp = getSpotifyApi();
    sp.require(['$views/throbber#Throbber'], function(Throbber) {

      var favs = document.getElementById('favs');
      var throbber = Throbber.forElement(favs);

    });
```

It is throwing this error." TypeError: Object $views/throbber#Throbber has no method 'match' ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Throbber component](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/views/views-throbber-throbber.html) is only available on 1.X API, using the syntax of your first code snippet.

In order to let the Spotify client know that you are using that version of the API you need to specify in your `manifest.json` file that are using the 1.X API by adding a `Dependencies` attribute including the `api` and `views` framework:

```
"Dependencies": {
    "api": "1.0.0",
    "views": "1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. How do I translate this code. var sp = getSpotifyApi();
    var models = require('$api/models');
 var views = require("$api/views"); into code, that is eligible with 1.X API?

Comment: Have a look at the [Migration Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/upgrade-guide/1.0.0). In the 1.X API you need to specify which views you are requiring, as you did before with the `Throbber`. In the migration guide you have an example with `Image`.